# yii validation rule allowEmpty not working

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii

I am uploading images in a form in an admin section in YII,

To get this working I must include it in the `rules` function in the model.

However the only way I can get the form working is to upload an image

```
public function rules()
    {
        // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
        // will receive user inputs.
        return array(
                     // Other rules
            array('slider_bg_image', 'file', 'types'=>'jpg, gif, png', 'allowEmpty'=>true),         

        );
    }
```

I get a blank screen when `allowEmpty` is set to `true`, but when I have it as `false` I am forced to upload the image.

I have errors turned on for the front end ,but cannot seem to do so for the backend.

Thank you

EDIT:

```
        <div class="row hide">
        <div class="span4"><label>Slide Background Image</label></div>
        <div class="span5"><?php echo $form->fileField($model,'slider_bg_image'); ?></div>
        <div class="span3"><?php echo $form->error($model,'slider_bg_image'); ?></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show the code for your form?

Comment: Where do you get a "blank screen" ??

Comment: Do you have access to the server? So that you could "tail" or review your error log and Yii log files?

Comment: Hi thanks I hadnt thought of finding the errors in the logs, my error wasnt directly related to the issue above, but basically when I had it set to true it was attempting to use data in the controller that didnt exist (because no image was uploaded), so some simple `if`s put in place solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code above,

I was simply attempting to use data in the controller that didnt exist (as an image wouldnt be uploaded), so I was receiving the error...

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function saveAs() on a non-object in /storage/www/mysite/core/protected/modules/admin/controllers/CustompageController.php

So I added in conditions in the controller to prevent the error.